# Why can't I use different generic Lists with Java record constructors

Tags: java, generics, java-record

According to [JEP 395](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) a record with additional constructors can be used:

```
public record Aliases(List<String> value) {    
    public Aliases(Integer raw) {
        this(List.of(raw.toString()));
    }    
}
```

Or with multiple values as array:

```
public record Aliases(List<String> value) {

    public Aliases(Integer... raws) {
        this(Arrays.stream(raws).map(Object::toString).toList());
    }

}
```

Where as using a typed List is not working:

```
public record Aliases(List<String> value) {

    public Aliases(List<Integer> rawList) {
        this(rawList.stream().map(Object::toString).toList());
    }

}
```

It says

> error: invalid canonical constructor in record Aliases

I would like to understand what is happening in behind and why it is not working?